# RMB Orbit, MMB Pan option

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I want a tinkercad style interface keymap. What should I do?
Fusion 360 has that option!
Very easy
Right click Orbit
Middle-click Pan
Wheel Zoom
Blender also has options
I wish

Sorry I used a language translator

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't believe Blender supports right-click panning due to the use of right-clicking for drop-down menus or selecting. However, you can change the default MMB action to pan, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+MMB will become orbit.

[image]

Comment: "*I don't believe Blender supports right-click panning due to the use of right-clicking for drop-down menus*" It does, you just have to remap all context menus to something else, or use a `release` event instead.

Comment: Remapping all the menus seems a bit overkill tbh. I guess using the release event would be the best for OP then